# notifyItemChanged() vs findViewHolderForAdapterPosition

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a Background Service to download some files and update the progress in the RecyclerView.
when the progress is changed the service will use a Callback to the Activity with the item that changed with the progress.
I want to know which one is Better in terms of Performance?

so do i have to do it like this using `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);`

```
@Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(String id, int pos, int progress) {
      MyViewHolder vh = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(pos);
      vh.progressBar.setProgress(progress);
}
```

**OR**

```
@Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(String id, int pos, int progress) {
     adapter.getProgressHashmap().put(id, progress);
     adapter.notifyItemChanged(pos);
}
```

and in my Adapter, I have a Hashmap

```
HashMap<String, Integer> progressHashmap = new HashMap<>();
```

now ,inside `onBindViewHolder` 
I will check if the hashmap contains the id then update the ProgressBar

```
 if (progressHashmap.containsKey(id)) {
        int progress = progressHashmap.get(id);
        holder.progressBar.setProgress(progress);
    }
```

Comment: both are the same

Comment: In theory, the correct approach is the 2nd. You are changing an item in your data and you need to tell the recycler view to update. The first one may fail (or return null) if you are scrolling and new data comes in. If you are concerned about the size, use `DiffUtil` to calculate the differences.

Answer (score 1):

I too would like to know more about this.

From my experience, obtaining the ViewHolder using `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(int position)` and updating only the data you need to update is more efficient than calling `notifyItemChanged(int position)`, because the latter invalidates and redraws the entire view.

The alternative is to call `notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload)`, pass `progress` as the payload and handle the progress update in `onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position, List<Object> payloads)`. I can give you more info about how to do this if you like.

I don't know which is the safest out of these methods, but if I had to guess it would be the latter because `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition` returns `null` if the RecyclerView is calculating its layout.

Comment: Using notifyItemChanged in combination with setting the itemAnimator to null fixes the performance issues for me. I don't see why the itemanimator should be called on notifyItemChanged though